# Meaning of the phrase "but one" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/5tw44SkkXQg). It is at 2 minute and 53 second.

> You have **but one** wild and precious life, my friends.

Comment: it means "only one". See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44900/what-does-but-mean-in-life-is-but-a-dream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

[**but**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/but) adverb (ONLY)

> *formal* only; just:
>
> *She's **but** a young girl!*

Applying this definition

> You have **only** one wild and precious life, my friends. 
> You have **just**
>   one wild and precious life, my friends.

Answer (score 0):

It is a somewhat poetic way of saying "only one".  It is not generally something you'd use in everyday speech, as you would probably say "only one".  But in the context of a witticism or coining a phrase, you tend to see "but one" used in place of "only one".

This said, if you strictly only use "only one," you're *not* incorrect.